# Connect / Login WordPress Hosted Website or Blog with NodeJs

Tags: plugins, javascript

I am trying to make A NodeJs CLI by which I can login in hosted WordPress account using NodeJs so I used [Passport-WordPress](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-wordpress/).

I wrote a code but I don't know what to do next and how to check if I am login to the WordPress or not.

this my wordpress hosted [Website](https://cswpsite.wordpress.com/)

Here is my code

### Index.js

```js
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const passport = require("passport");

const WordpressStrategy = require("passport-wordpress").Strategy;

function wordpress() {
  inquirer
    .prompt([
      {
        name: "wpWebsite",
        message: " Enter Your Website or Blog:",
      },
      {
        name: "wpUserName",
        message: " Enter UserName or Email: ",
      },
      {
        type: "password",
        name: "wpPassword",
        message: " Enter Password: ",
      },
    ])
    .then((answers, cb) => {
      passport.use(
        new WordpressStrategy(
          {
            clientID: answers.wpUserName,
            clientSecret: answers.wpPassword,
            callbackURL: `https://example.com/auth/wordpress/callback`,
          },
          function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(done);
          }
        )
      );
    });
}
```

anyone have any idea am I doing correct or not ?

I have Few question here such as

1. What is accessToken here?
2. What is refreshToken here?
3. What is profile? Is the profile is same as email id or username?
4. what is callbackUrl? Do I have to put my website URL ?

Comment: This is really related to a 3rd-party library that connects to a 3rd-party hosting service, and doesn't actually involve any code or functionality from the WordPress software. This is a question you're going to need to ask the library developers, or the more general audience at stackoverflow.com. It's not on topic here.

Comment: All four questions here are common components of the OAuth standard. Here's [a nice overview of OAuth 2](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) and what these components are.